# Access voice style the user has set for Bixby (e.g. Stephanie/John/...)

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

For my capsule I need the information if the user has set Bixby to talk to them in a male or a female voice, because it will influence what my response looks like using [SSML](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/template.speech). Is there a way for me to find out what voice style the user has set?

To be clear: I'm looking for a way which Voice Style the user has set in Bixby Settings.

[image: Voice Style]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, what you are asking for is not supported. To be clear, there is no way to access which named voice the user has chosen, or the assigned gender of that voice.

Answer (score 1):

Bixby has limited support for ssml at the moment, and the lang tag is the only available ssml element.  For example:

```
<lang xml:lang=\"fr-FR\" voice=\"M01\">chat</lang>
```

[More info on ssml for Bixby](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/template.speech).  Stay tuned, I'd imagine they'll be adding new features in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but you misunderstood: I'm looking for a way to find out what Voice the user has set to be used in Bixby Settings -> Language and voice style.

Comment: It looks like your original question was edited since I responded?  You said you wanted to respond with ssml, and I didn't see that your original post had a reference to the fact that only lang is supported.  To answer your question about the Bixby settings, I'm not aware of a way to determine that specific setting on the user device.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to add clarification. I know how to use SSML, thank you for your answer regardless!